# TypeError: Crafty.scene is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error, electron, craftyjs

I have a small problem. I'm developing a game using CraftyJS and I need to use Electron to run it, but Electron throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Crafty.scene is not a function
at Level1.js:4
```

Why does it do this? Here's the relevant code + markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overtime-game</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="game"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='./node_modules/craftyjs/dist/crafty.js'></script>
  <script src='./Level1.js'>
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//Relevant code:
Crafty.scene('main', function() {
Crafty.init(500,500, document.getElementById('game'));
// rest of Crafty.scene...
}
Crafty.scene('main')
```

Comment: What does logging `Crafty` show you?

Comment: @pushkin Nothing. It appears to be a problem with Electron, cause i can use CraftyJS using Beefy and Browserify just fine.

Comment: Nothing as in `undefined`, or you don't see any logs? If it were `undefined`, your error would be something like "cannot read property 'scene' of undefined", so I would suspect it's the latter. Try using breakpoints to examine what it's set to. Try requiring the npm module in your JS instead of using `script`

Comment: @pushkin Do you mean `require` in the HTML page? cause it cant be used in HTML. if you mean the actual JS, the module is required: `var Crafty = require('craftyjs')`

Answer (score 0):

FIXED ON ELECTRON FORUMS:Apparently if you require a module in the file Electron will not look in `node_modules`.
https://discuss.atom.io/t/solved-typeerror-crafty-scene-is-not-a-function/61273